# are condition variables, message queues used for inter process communication and messagebrokers(kafka) the same?

Tags: multithreading, apache-kafka, operating-system, message-queue

In university level course on operating systems,it is told that inter process communication can take place using message queues.
Also, in mutli-threading, condition variables are queues used to solve the producer-consumer problem.
Recently I have been working with kafka.

are the above the three, kafka, message queues in inter process comm. and condition variables in multi threading the same?

thnx in advance

Answer (score 0):

A message queue / broker is not the same as a queue data structure.

Queues and interprocress communications happen within the context of one machine, while message brokers are often external servers comprised of several machines that communicate over some TCP protocol for their clients. You'd need to dig into their source code to find how each server utilizes threads/locking, but typical users shouldn't concern themselves with that.

Comment: got it, and what about conditional variables used in multithreading, are they same as message brokers, or internally used in brokers.

Comment: Think you mean "condition variables". But I'm not a message broker core developer, so cannot say how they interface with the operating system. Kafka for one example relies on Zookeeper and Raft protocol for distributed locking

Comment: Condition variables are inter-thread synchronization objects. I'm sure you can find plenty of descriptions of how they work and when to use them. But they are not message queues.